# Side-by-side examples of skeuomorphic vs flat design?

Tags: android, ios, smartphone, skeuomorphism

Googling for what's news in Android Lollipop, I came across the concept of skeuomorphic design for the first time. I understand that this term means a digital design that retains aesthetic features from its physical origins.

I've also read about the examples, e.g. wooden bookshelves in iBook, but hope to see a side-by-side pictorial comparison of the recent move from skeuomorphic to flat design by both Apple and Google. Being a regular consumer, I've actually NOT noticed this move until I read about the concept.

Disclaimer: This question is from an ordinary smartphone user, not a UX designer.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about showing examples of different design techniques. There is no single accurate answer to this subjective question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skeuomorphism was a defining characteristic of iOS until last year's release of "flat" iOS7. A quick Google search for [iOS6 vs iOS7 flat design](https://www.google.com/search?q=iOS6+vs+iOS7+flat+design) returns tons of design articles, comparisons, gripes, rants, etc. The [images tab of that search](https://www.google.com/search?q=iOS6%20vs%20iOS7%20flat%20design&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=zJFjVKaqGY7ToATLooDABQ&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAQ&biw=1237&bih=912) has lots of side-by-side examples.

Some key differences include reduction (or outright elimination) of depth cues like shadows, bevels, and gradients; also reduction of "realistic" textures designed to look like wood, glass,  metal, or fabric (the "green felt" of iOS game center is a common example). An extreme example of the shift in design is how they turned obvious, tactile, gradient buttons into nothing more than a borderless hyperlink.

Google's most recent shift for Android is toward what they call "[Material Design](http://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html#introduction-principles)," which combines these ideas. They use flat, bold color with minimal shadows, but animations that aim to mimic working with real objects like paper & ink. Although visually "flat" the interaction is still "lifelike." This is similar in some ways to animations and dynamics in iOS7/8 - visually flat, but bouncy & responsive in a way that feels natural.